# How can I increase the length of the legend symbol in the legend box in PGFPlots

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots

I want to increase the length of the legend symbol (like solid lines, dashed lines, dot dashed lines, dotted lines etc) in the legend box since for dot-dashed lines the length of the symbol is too small to be differentiated by other symbols in the legend box that I use.[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can adjust the details of the legend through `pgfplotsset` where you can also adjust the start and end "coordinates" of the legend handles, .e.g,

```
\pgfplotsset{legend image code/.code={%
   \draw plot coordinates {(0cm,0cm) (0.5cm,0cm)};
    }
}
```

Here is a MWE:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\pgfplotsset{legend image code/.code={
        \draw plot coordinates {(0.cm,0cm) (1.5cm,0cm)};
    }
}


\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \begin{axis}
            [legend entries={$E^\ast/E_c=5$, $E^\ast/E_c=3$}]
            \addplot[no markers, red] coordinates {(0,0) (0.4, 0.3) (0.8, 0.5)};
            \addplot[no markers, blue] coordinates {(0.3, 0) (0.4, 1) (0.9, 0)};
        \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}           
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer @BanDoP. \pgfplotsset command worked. Now, I can adjust the start and the end of the legend handles and the length of the symbol in the legend box is bigger as I wanted to be.

Comment: Here is the solution that I obtained using the answer of @BanDoP: [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QDMVg.png)

Comment: Great, in that case, could you mark the answer as correct?

Comment: Just did it @BanDoP. Thanks again.